What is the limited access permission?
When I share a folder or file with an user then the user gets automatically also added at the site level with limited access permission.
If I remove the access of this user, even then the user continues to have site level limited access permission.
What does limited access permission mean?
What will happen if this permission (for a user) is removed? Will the user continues to see the shared file/folder?

It is explained in this Microsoft article about Permission levels in SharePoint

Limited Access
Enables a user or group to browse to a site page or
library to access a specific content item when they do not have
permissions to open or edit any other items in the site or library.
This level is automatically assigned by SharePoint when you provide
access to one specific item. You cannot assign Limited Access
permissions directly to a user or group yourself. Instead, when you
assign edit or open permissions to the single item, SharePoint
automatically assigns Limited Access to other required locations, such
as the site or library in which the single item is located. This
allows SharePoint to render the user interface correctly and show the
user some context around their location in the site. Limited Access
does not grant any additional permissions to the user, so they can't
see or access any other content.

The limited access permission for the user is retained when the originally shared single item permission is revoked. The limited access permission does not have to be removed with the single item permissions, because on its own it does not provide any access.

Is there a way to cleanup the limited access users after their folder permission are removed?

Not that I'm aware of. It's been that way since SharePoint 2007 at least, and it has never caused any issues. You can't add these permissions and you can't remove them, unless you totally recreate the site.

I tested and I can remove user from limited access permission and the user looses access to the folder/file

Why would you remove limited access permissions for users that still have items shared with them? Of course that will destroy their access. The limited access is required on top of the access to the individual item.
